# Requiring a module using its path from the project's root?

Tags: racket

I'm making a web application. Consider such structure

```
ProjectName/racket/Servlet.rkt
ProjectName/racket/chart/barchart/BarChart.rkt
ProjectName/template/barchart.svg
```

How can I inside the `BarChart.rkt` module require the `Barchart.svg` template, without using any `..`? Ideally, if the application is launched from ProjectName (i.e. `cd ProjectName; racket racket/Servlet.rkt`), the require part would resemble `(require "template/barchart.svg")`, but use ProjectName as a root instead of the relative ProjectName/racket/barchart.

Comment: Have you looked at [`path-up`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Frequire..rkt%29._path-up%29%29)? It isn't exactly what you want but it might be useful in setting up a “project environment” like this. It allows you to specify a path that's relative to the current source-file, or if that doesn't exist, relative to the parent, or if that doesn't exist, relative to the grandparent, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1) Naive method

You can use `(define-runtime-path)`:

**ProjectName/chart/barchart/BarChart.rkt:**

```
#lang racket/base
(provide barchart-template)
(require
  racket/runtime-path
  racket/file)

(define-runtime-path barchart.svg "../../template/barchart.svg")

(define (barchart-template)
  (file->string barchart.svg))
```

**ProjectName/Servlet.rkt:**

```
#lang racket/base
(require ProjectName/chart/barchart/Barchart)

(displayln (barchart-template)) ;; prints the content of the SVG file, wherever you are
```

## 2) Better method

### Registering your package

From my experience, the best way to handle paths when developing a Racket application is making a package, then use the classic `(require my-package/my-module)` syntax instead of using relative paths.

For example, if you have a project like this:

```
ProjectName/Servlet.rkt
ProjectName/chart/barchart/BarChart.rkt
ProjectName/template/barchart.svg
```

By adding an `info.rkt` file at the root of your project, you transform it into a package.

```
echo "#lang info" > ProjectName/info.rkt
```

Then call `cd ProjectName; raco pkg install`.

Then you can require BarChart.rkt in any file with `(require ProjectName/chart/BarChart)`.

Why am I telling you all this? Because now, you can start your application from any folder:

`racket -l ProjectName/Servlet`

Which will allow you to test easily if your paths are handled whatever the directory you are running the program in.

### Getting rid of `../..`

Now that your package is registered in your local database, you can easily find it's root directory using `(pkg-directory)` from `pkg/lib`:

**ProjectName/chart/barchart/BarChart.rkt:**

```
#lang racket/base
(provide barchart-template)
(require
  racket/file
  pkg/lib)

(define (barchart-template)
  (define template.svg (build-path (pkg-directory "ProjectName")
                                   "template/barchart.svg"))
  (file->string template.svg))
```